# Ktor: How to serialize/deserialise JSON-API (vnd.api+json)

Tags: json, rest, kotlin, ktor

I'm looking to rewrite a spring javafx application in Kotlin using Ktor. I am new to both Spring and Ktor.

I'm having trouble using Ktor to figure out how to approach serialization and deserialisation of POJOs. (These POJOs are part of a common library).

The API I'm trying to serve requests to with Ktor uses:

- Hibernate ORM as ORM mapper
- Elide with RSQL filters to serve [JSON-API conform data](https://jsonapi.org/)

For example "data/event" would return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "event",
      "id": "15b6c19a-6084-4e82-ada9-6c30e282191f",
      "attributes": {
        "imageUrl": null,
        "name": "some text",
        "type": "NUMERIC"
      }
    }, // and more event objects
  ]
}
```

Looking at the codebase in the spring application, it looks like they are using a RestTemplate to deserialise the above into an Event class (which only has an id, imageUrl, name and type as variables). Spring seems to automatically know how to get a POJO from JSON-API.

How can I do the same with Ktor? I tried the simplest:

```
val response = client.request<List<Event>>("data/event")
```

With the serialiser as gson:

```
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = GsonSerializer()
    }
```

But this results in a list of Event objects with none of their variables correctly set.

I have to make a wrapper class:

```
data class MyWrapper(val data: List<Event>)
```

And with that it will populate the list with the objects `id` set correctly, but none of the other attributes. So by default it looks like Ktor isnt configured for JSON-API. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe JSON:API is not supported out of the box. You need to write your own serializer, or use another wrapper class:

```kotlin
class JSONAPI<T>(val type: String, val id: String, val attributes: T)
data class MyWrapper(val data: List<JSONAPI<Event>>)
```

The problem here is that all fields in `Event` except of `id` will be filled. So you will need to adjust deserialization result:

```kotlin
 val response: List<Event> = client.request<MyWrapper>("data/event").data.filterNotNull().map { it.attributes.copy(id = it.id) }
```